# Why do I get null values when parsing my XML document

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I'm currently trying to parse som XML data, I can't show the entire document because it contains a lot of sensitive information so I can only provide a snippet.

This is how I parse my xml

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Rss));
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("urlToData");

var k = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

As I said I can't provide the actual URL so I pasted some test data here.
https://hatebin.com/pspnhpihlz

Anyways, when I look at `k` to see what it holds, the first `Description` contains data, but as I start diving deeper into it, for instance `Items` -> and select an item and look at the `Description` the `src` and `p` is null, and I don't know why, there is obviously data there.

Here are the objects that was generated when I used a XML2C# generator

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "img")]
    public class Img
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "src")]
        public string Src { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "alt")]
        public string Alt { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "description")]
    public class Description
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "img")]
        public Img Img { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "p")]
        public string P { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "item")]
    public class Item
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "link")]
        public string Link { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "author")]
        public string Author { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "pubDate")]
        public string PubDate { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "description")]
        public Description Description { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "category")]
        public string Category { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "channel")]
    public class Channel
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "link")]
        public string Link { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "pubDate")]
        public string PubDate { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "generator")]
        public string Generator { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "copyright")]
        public string Copyright { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "lastBuildDate")]
        public string LastBuildDate { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "language")]
        public string Language { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "item")]
        public List<Item> Item { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "rss")]
    public class Rss
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "channel")]
        public Channel Channel { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "version")]
        public string Version { get; set; }
    }
```

And as I said, it parses the data just fine, it's just that inside `Items` each `Item` has a description of null inside their `src` and `p` property, and I have no idea why.

Why is that?

Comment: Your sample file has an `<item><link` too much towards the end. When I remove this, the code works as expected. Please provide a [mcve] that shows the problem.

Comment: If that is a standard rss feed you can use the [already invented wheel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/parsers/rssparser)

Comment: @NineBerry I would post the url to the XML data but it contains sensitive data, so I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: @RileyVarga Build a working example xml file with random data that produces the problem.

Comment: When you did it, did you check inside the `Items` collection? each items has a `Description` but the two properties inside it `Img` and `p` are null

Comment: The tags Description and src are another layer of tags and required additional classes to get the data.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I'm not quite following? Aditional classes as in classes that extracts the src value etc?

Comment: @RileyVarga Works as expected https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxanL.png

Comment: @NineBerry Updated my comment, forgot to add the link in there

Comment: @RileyVarga Yes, it works as expected. Img is null when the <img> node is missing in the xml. But that is expected.

Comment: @NineBerry That's strange, am I missing some encoding or something?

Comment: We can't know because you haven't provided a full [mcve] yet!

Comment: If you look at the source code, you see that the contents of the description tag are not xml, but plain text.  `<description>&lt;img src="https://img8.ntm.eu/om/public/img/6432049/1217185022/har-kommer-de-att-ligga-de-un?w=790" alt="" /&gt;&lt;p&gt;Just nu är det inte så mycket att se - men till våren ska det nya fjärrkylasystemet bli en sevärdhet.&lt;/p&gt;</description>`

Comment: I can reproduce it now. It's because the content of the description tag is not part of XML document. See previous comment.

Comment: Ah interesting! So what's the proper way of dealing with that? I tried making a simple string property to try to catch it but that didnt work, assuming it didnt parse that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `description` tag within the `item` tag does not contain further XML structure, but this is just a string.

Change the definition of the `Item` class like this, replacing the type `Description` with just `string`.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "item")]
public class Item
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "link")]
    public string Link { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "author")]
    public string Author { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "pubDate")]
    public string PubDate { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "category")]
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

In the provided data, the string contains HTML formatting. If you want to parse this string further, use `XmlTextReader` again on the string.

Comment: Ah! I see what you mean now! That's a lot easier to parse now as well

Comment: Oh, is it possible to parse both the URL and the text using `XmlTextReader`?